# Upload file suggested by microsoft doesn't work for me in CGI

Tags: c#, networking, windows-mobile, upload, file-upload

we would like to upload a .zip file in windows mobile to .cgi script running at server.
in desktop we have "Webclient.uploadfile" API, it does't support in winmo. do we have any alternative methods to upload
file in windows mobile.. we tried a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446517.aspx)

method suggested by Microsoft, but it doesn't work for our CGI script.
please let us know any alternatives available for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey just follw up this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446517.aspx)

it has detail steps to upload file to server from windows mobile